# Check coverage between current branch and master circleci

Tags: continuous-deployment, jestjs, circleci

I've a project that's checked by the circleci and fails if broke some test. I want the circleci to fails if the current branch coverage is smaller than the coverage from master. I'm using jest for the coverage. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a script that:
 1) Clone the project
 2) Runs the coverage command to the master
 3) Saves the result
 4) Download the current branch
 5) Runs the coverage command to the current branch
 6) Saves the result
 7) Compares the results
 8) If the current branch result it's smaller than the master results, the circleci fails.

If you're interest in more information you can see the post that I created: https://medium.com/@marinahaack/fails-the-circleci-build-according-to-the-coverage-of-the-current-branch-with-the-master-5ca7a306a472

Answer (score 1):

You can use: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#coveragethreshold-object.

So, when the --coverage run in your CI it will throws an exception.